# Adding elements from html node to vuejs data

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

```
<tasks>
    @foreach ($task as $tasks)
        <task>{{ $task->name }} [{{ $task->completed }}]</task>
    @endforeach
</tasks>
```

Above is the code I use to output the list of tasks from DB. Here's my Vue component:

```
Vue.component('tasks', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <task v-for="task in tasks"> {{ task.name }} </task>
        </div>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            tasks: [
                { name: "task", completed: true }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

How can I add tasks outputted in PHP foreach loop to a Vue component data tasks? I suppose I need use props, but how exactly? I'm putting my components in `/resources/assets/js/components`. I'm using Laravel as you've probably already guessed. Thank you.

Comment: Get tasks as `json_encode`d string and output'em in component's code. Or load them with ajax/axios on component's load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your tasks in as a prop:

```
<tasks :tasks="@json($tasks)"></tasks>
```

Then set up that prop in the component:

```
Vue.component('tasks', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <task v-for="task in tasks"> {{ task.name }} </task>
        </div>
    `,
    props:['tasks']
});
```

If you have a separate component for individual tasks you can again pass the task as a prop:

```
<task v-for="task in tasks" :task="task"></task>
```

Comment: Wow. Just absolutely wow! Beautiful. However, for me `"@json($tasks)"` didn't work, but `'@json($tasks)'` did (cause `@json` returns a string with double quotes).